# Why PHP PDO bindParam return null if include jQuery file

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

On every page I have jQuery modal which contains a contact form and which on every page need sent data to different email address. When a form is submitted I need to display successful response using `json_encode`. Also on every page I use page identifier as `$pages_id=1`, `$pages_id=2`, etc., for identify which form is submitted.  However, very important, without jQuery file, complete my PHP code it's executed correctly, all data are successfully inserted into database and in Xdebug I also see that code on every line it's executed successfully. But, if I include jQuery file then in Xdebug the value for `$pages_id` return null. I exactly think at this line of code:

```
$query = "SELECT owners_email.email_address_id, email_address, owner_name, owner_property, owner_sex, owner_type FROM visitneum.owners_email INNER JOIN visitneum.pages ON (pages.email_address_id = owners_email.email_address_id) WHERE `owner_sex`='M' AND `owner_type`='other' AND `pages_id` = ?";
$dbstmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$dbstmt->bindParam(1,$pages_id);
$dbstmt->execute();
```

However, below is my complete PHP code:

```
<?php
// set error reporting
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

$fname = $tel = $userMail = $userMessage = $email_address_id = "";
$fname_error = $tel_error = $userMail_error = $userMessage_error = "";
$error=false;
//Load the config file
$dbHost = "secret";
$dbUser = "secret";
$dbPassword = "secret";
$dbName = "secret";
$dbCharset = "utf8";
$pdo="";
try{
    $dsn = "mysql:host=" . $dbHost . ";dbName=" . $dbName . ";charset=" . $dbCharset;
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbUser, $dbPassword);
    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8");
    $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Connection error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/SMTP.php';
require 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
if(isset($_POST['submitOwner'])){
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $tel = $_POST['tel'];
    $userMail = $_POST['userMail'];
    $userMessage = $_POST['userMessage'];
if(empty($_POST['fname'])){
        $error=true;
        $fname_error = "Name and surname cannot be empty!";
    }else{
        $fname = $_POST['fname'];   
        if(!preg_match("/^[a-zšđčćžA-ZŠĐČĆŽ\s]*$/", $fname)){
            $fname_error = "Name and surname can only contain letters and spaces!";
        }
    }
    if(empty($_POST['tel'])) {
        $tel_error = "Phone number cannot be blank!";
    }else{
        $tel = $_POST['tel'];
        if(!preg_match('/^[\+]?[0-9]{9,15}$/', $tel)) {
            $tel_error = "The phone number should contain a minimum of 9 to 15 numbers!";
        }
    }
if(empty($_POST['userMail'])){
        $userMail_error = "Email cannot be blank!";
    }else{
        $userMail = $_POST['userMail'];
        if(!filter_var($userMail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $userMail_error = "Email address is incorrect!";
        }
    }
    if(empty($_POST['userMessage'])) {
        $userMessage_error = "The content of the message cannot be empty!";
    }else{
        $userMessage = $_POST['userMessage'];
        if(!preg_match("/^[a-zšđčćžA-ZŠĐČĆŽ0-9 ,.!?\'\"]*$/", $userMessage)){
            $userMessage_error = "The content of the message cannot be special characters!";
        }
    }
if($fname_error == '' && $tel_error == '' && $userMail_error == '' && $userMessage_error == ''){
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'secret';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'secret';
    $mail->Password = 'secret';
    $mail->Port = 465; // 587
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // tls
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;  
    $mail->setFrom('secret@secret.com');
    $mail->Subject = "New message from visit-neum.com";
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $query = "SELECT owners_email.email_address_id, email_address, owner_name, owner_property, owner_sex, owner_type FROM visitneum.owners_email INNER JOIN visitneum.pages ON (pages.email_address_id = owners_email.email_address_id) WHERE `owner_sex`='M' AND `owner_type`='other' AND `pages_id` = ?";
$dbstmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$dbstmt->bindParam(1,$pages_id); 
$dbstmt->execute(); //in Xdebug this line of code return NULL for $pages_id if include jQuery file
$emails_other = $dbstmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$jsonData=array();
    if(is_array($emails_other) && count($emails_other)>0){
      foreach($emails_other as $email_other){
        //var_dump($email_other['email_address']);
        $mail->addAddress($email_other['email_address']);
        $body_other = "<p>Dear {$email_other['owner_name']}, <br>" . "You just received a message from the site <a href='https://www.visit-neum.com'>visit-neum.com</a><br>Details of your message are below:</p><p><strong>From: </strong>" . ucwords($fname) . "<br><strong>Phone: </strong>" . $tel . "<br><strong>E-mail: </strong>" .strtolower($userMail)."<br><strong>Message: </strong>" . $userMessage . "</p>";
$mail->Body = $body_other;
if($mail->send()){
            
            $mail = "INSERT INTO visitneum.contact_owner(fname, tel, userMail, userMessage, email_address_id) VALUES(:fname, :tel, :userMail, :userMessage, :email_address_id)";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($mail);
            $stmt->execute(['fname' => $fname, 'tel' => $tel, 'userMail' => $userMail, 'userMessage' => $userMessage, 'email_address_id' => $email_other['email_address_id']]);

                // Load AJAX
                if($error==false){
                    $information['response'] = "success";
                    $information['content'] = "Thanks " . ucwords($fname) . "! Your message has been successfully sent to the owner of property! You will get an answer soon!";
                    $jsonData[] = $information;
                }
}//end if mail send         
else{   
    $information['response'] = "error";
    $information['content'] = "An error has occurred! Please try again..." . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    $jsonData[]=$information;  
}
echo(json_encode($jsonData));
} // end foreach($emails_other as $email_other)
} // end if(is_array($emails_other) && count($emails_other)>0)
} // end if validation
} // end submitOwner
} // end REQUEST METHOD = POST
```

And below you can see submitHandler for my jQuery file which causes me problem:

```
 submitHandler: function(form){  
      var formData=jQuery("#contactOwner").serialize();
      console.log(formData);
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/inc/FormProcess.php",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: formData,
      success:function(jsonData) {
         jQuery("#responseOwner").text(jsonData.content);
         console.log(jsonData);
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                    console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
                  }
      }); // Code for AJAX Ends
// Clear all data after submit
      var resetForm = document.getElementById('contactOwner').reset();
      return false;
    } // end submitHandler
```

And the page which contains contact form is below:

```
<?php
include_once './inc/FormProcess.php';
?>
<form  spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" id='contactOwner' class='form' name='contactOwner' action='' method='POST'>
<h4 id="responseOwner" class="success">
<!-- This will hold response from the server --></h4>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Vaši podaci</legend>
        <div class="form-control halb InputIconBg"><input minlength="6" type="text" class="input username" name="fname" placeholder="Your name and surname ..." value="<?php echo Input::get('fname'); ?>"><i class="fas fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="error"><?=$fname_error; ?></span></div><!-- end .form-control -->
            
        <div class="form-control halb InputIconBg"><input minlength="9" type="text" class="input phone" name="tel" placeholder="Your phone number..." value="<?php echo Input::get('tel'); ?>"><i class="fas fa-phone-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="error"><?=$tel_error; ?></span></div><!-- end .form-control -->

        <div class="form-control single InputIconBg"><input type="text" class="input mail" name="userMail" placeholder="Your e-mail..." value="<?php echo Input::get('userMail'); ?>" autocomplete="email"><i id="" class="fas fa-envelope owner_icon" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="error"><?=$userMail_error; ?></span></div><!-- end .form-control --> 
            
        <div class="form-control InputIconBg"><textarea maxlength="1000" name="userMessage" class="textinput message" cols="46" rows="8" placeholder="Your message..."><?php echo Input::get('userMessage'); ?></textarea><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt owner_icon" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="error"><?=$userMessage_error; ?></span></div><!-- end .form-control -->
            
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" class="btn_submit" id="submitOwner" name="submitOwner" value="SENT"/>
</form>
<script defer src="/JS/validateOwner.js"></script>
```

So, I can not figure out what is the problem and why $pages_id return null when include jQuery file. Also, I was forget to mention that code inside line `if(is_array($emails_other) && count($emails_other)>0){` return number 0, so complete seguent code isn't executed, but of course this is normal, because $pages_id is null. However, I hope that somebody understand what is the problem and so, thanks in advance for any kind of help that you can give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

page_id is null in your script because you dont set it in the script.

So why not just adding an hidden input field in your froms with the page id and then in your PHP code

$page_id = $_POST['pageId'];

---

i think you did not understood ajax correclty. if you post your data to /inc/FormProcess.php it is not like an include before, where you could create variables first and then include it. AJax is like a sub call to the script. it is like if you would open ONLY this scrirpt provided in URL. so at this point you dont have your variables.

you need to get the variables or send your ajax request NOT to /inc/FormProcess.php but to the script where you define the variable

Comment: I was set $pages_id at the top on every page and this what make me very confuse is that complete my PHP code is executed successfully if I dont include jQuery file. Perhaps, all data are inserted into database correctly, on every page with different pages_id which match $pages_id of the page. But, just in case when I include jQuery file then bindParam for $pages_id return null

Comment: @MirnesGlamočić yes but here you call via ajax JUST the inc/FormProcess.php and in this file, you do not set the pages_id.

if you call a script via ajax, it is like if you would open ONLY the script in a new Browser tab. try it. open in your tab the page /inc/FormProcess.php you will see the $pages_id is empty there

Comment: Ajax URLs is like Open new tab in the background.

Comment: thanks a lot, everything make me sense, just can not understand how to write input type hidden inside /inc/FormProcess.php, because my website is like booking, I have website with multiple pages where you can contact owner of different property on every page, so I just include on every page /inc/FormProcess.php as contactOwner.php where it's contact form as  validateOwner.js where is jQuery validation and this submitHandler with Ajax call.

Comment: @MirnesGlamočić if you can find out which page id you currently have you can set it in the ajax handler

 var formData=jQuery("#contactOwner").serialize();
formData['page_id'] =1; 

and then in your PHP Code $page_id =$_POST['page_id']

Comment: I hope that I understand you. However, I dont paste code of my form because I think that there dont have errors, so after all inputs and textarea I need to write input type="hidden" but how to replace the value of the page automatically, e.g. if the user is on the page of the Hotel Paris that the form knows that its page_id is 6, or if the user is on the page of the Hotel Berlin that the form knows that its page_id is. 8 etc.

Comment: @MirnesGlamočić i dont know, how do you set it in PHP without jquery? i cant answer the question without knowing the code. i think this part is up to you. you need somehow to know which form belongs to whom based on the form.

Comment: I was edit my post, adding my contact form too, so please check up and let me know how to writte input type hidden, because I sincerely never use this type of input. However, input type hidden must have value, but I need that this value change automatically on every page, based on page_id which is set outside of script. Hm? So confusing...

Comment: @MirnesGlamočić just <input type="hidden" name="page_id" value="1">  and you can set the value for every form

Comment: but I have just 1 file for contact form, which I include on every page. So, in contact form if I write value="1" this mean for all contact forms that the value is 1. i dont repeat my self writing again and agian the some code, so on every page I just include contact form as header, footer etc. what is the some.

Comment: @MirnesGlamočić but you wirte "Also on every page I use page identifier as $pages_id=1, $pages_id=2" 

so i assume you can write in your from <input type="hidden" name="page_id" value="<?= $pages_id?>" >

Comment: I was write `<input type="hidden" name="pages_id" value="<?=$pages_id?>">` before input type submit and pages_id=$_POST['pages_id']; in inc/formProcess.php but now when a form is submitted dont happend nothing. Perhaps, all text remain inside inputs

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add input type hidden at the end of the form, so my correct form should look like this:

```
<form  spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" id='contactOwner' class='form ajax' name='contactOwner' action='' method='POST'>
<h4 id="responseOwner" class="success">
<!-- This will hold response from the server --></h4>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Vaši podaci</legend>
        <div class="form-control halb InputIconBg"><input minlength="6" type="text" class="input username" name="fname" placeholder="Vaše ime i prezime..." value="<?php echo Input::get('fname'); ?>"><i class="fas fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="error"><?=$fname_error; ?></span></div><!-- end .form-control -->
            
        <div class="form-control halb InputIconBg"><input minlength="9" type="text" class="input phone" name="tel" placeholder="Vaš broj telefona..." value="<?php echo Input::get('tel'); ?>"><i class="fas fa-phone-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="error"><?=$tel_error; ?></span></div><!-- end .form-control -->

        <div class="form-control single InputIconBg"><input type="text" class="input mail" name="userMail" placeholder="Vaš e-mail..." value="<?php echo Input::get('userMail'); ?>" autocomplete="email"><i id="" class="fas fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="error"><?=$userMail_error; ?></span></div><!-- end .form-control --> 
            
        <div class="form-control InputIconBg"><textarea maxlength="1000" name="userMessage" class="textinput message" cols="46" rows="8" placeholder="Vaša poruka..."><?php echo Input::get('userMessage'); ?></textarea><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt owner_icon" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="error"><?=$userMessage_error; ?></span></div><!-- end .form-control -->
            
    </fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" name="pages_id" value="<?=$pages_id?>">
    <input type="submit" class="btn_submit" id="submitOwner" name="submitOwner" value="POŠALJI"/>
</form>
```